# Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack in webservice Call

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services

i have added a webservice to my project in visual studio 2013 WindowsFormApplication project.
i have a class named `webserviceController` and i manage all my webservice methods in there.
my webservice has a method named `sendSms` .
i called `SendSms` in program.cs

but i faced the

`System.Threading.ThreadAbortException`

that has

```
Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.
```

as inner exception.

i found that, it must be related to program.cs, because all my webservice methods are act as the same in program.cs, and they work fine in other classes or forms.

this is my code in `webserviceController` class

```
 public void SendSms(long mobileNumber)
    {
      ThreadManager.NewThreadStart(delegate()
        {
          try
           { 
             x.sendSms(mobileNumber);
           }  
          catch(System.Threading.ThreadAbortException) { }
        });
```

`x` is my webservice instance.

and here is my code in `Program.cs`

```
y.SendSms(mobileNumber);
```

`y` is my webserviceController instance

any idea whats the reason?

PS. i use .NetFramework 2.0

Comment: i found that it might be related to the **static** class.
my `program.cs` is static. i moved my code to another static class and i got the same exception.